# Creating a custom component inside a table without directive selector

Tags: angular, html-table

I made a custom row component with some `<td>`'s inside. It worked with the directive selector but i activated tslint in my project and it throws error that i can't use directive selector in a component.

I don't want to disable this so im trying to change it to a component selector. But the table layout breaks when it is used a component selector.

Is there a solution for this problem or do i have to disable the check?

I tried using `<ng-container>` but its not what i need (i think)

the custom component:

```
<td>{{getProductName(neighbour)}}</td>
<td>{{getVersion(neighbour)}}</td>
<td>{{getProjectName()}}</td>
<td>{{neighbour.ip}}</td>
<td>{{neighbour.mac}}</td>
<td>{{mapHardwareType(neighbour)}}</td>
<td>
    <button [disabled]="!reachable" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" (click)="open()">
        <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> <span [translate]="'OPEN'"></span>
    </button>
</td>
```

table:

```
<table class="table table-default table-responsive">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th [translate]="'PRODUCT'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'VERSION_AND_DATE'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'PROJECT_NAME'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'IP'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'MAC'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'HARDWARE'"></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let n of neighbours|filter:{keys: searchKeys, str: search}">
                <tr>
                    <app-neighbour-row [neighbour]="n"></app-neighbour-row>
                </tr>
            </ng-container>

      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I tried tr but the parent element breaks the layout too. I prefer the table because i used it in a lot of pages. Maybe i disable the lint.

Comment: no, do not disable lint, the error has a reason. You may try `<ng-template>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you component has two drawback.

1. I does not include any good functionality that you would like to reuse.
2. It breakup the html markup. The `<th>` and the `<td>` are hard coupled anyway.

I would recommend you to remove the component and use this code:

```
<table class="table table-default table-responsive">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th [translate]="'PRODUCT'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'VERSION_AND_DATE'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'PROJECT_NAME'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'IP'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'MAC'"></th>
                <th [translate]="'HARDWARE'"></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let neighbour of neighbours|filter:{keys: searchKeys, str: search}">
                  <td>{{getProductName(neighbour)}}</td>
                  <td>{{getVersion(neighbour)}}</td>
                  <td>{{getProjectName()}}</td>
                  <td>{{neighbour.ip}}</td>
                  <td>{{neighbour.mac}}</td>
                  <td>{{mapHardwareType(neighbour)}}</td>
                  <td>
                      <button [disabled]="!reachable" class="btn btn-sm btn-   primary" (click)="open(neighbour)">
                      <i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> <span [translate]="'OPEN'"></span>
                     </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>    
      </tbody>
</table>
```

It's just easier to understand and to change. Less impact on the html. The getProductName,getVersion and getProjectName can be removed if you prepare the neighbours list data in the component before you loop it. Rxjs got some cool features on this